# AJAX / Java persistence

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, gwt, asynchronous

I'm new to server side.
I'm creating a database app for my company that stores links to all our marketing videos. Each entry is a url(to video), description, industry etc.

I already have the front end somewhat set up in HTML/JavaScript. Using a local XML source file, it populates a list with video names, and has text fields for all props of the video item.

Here's my question:
How do I handle updating my view when I send the form data (new entry) to the back end?
Should I insert a new entry based on local data?
Should I wait for the response from the server, and if success then update view based on local data?
Or, same as above, but update view based on back end data?
The goal is to make sure my view always reflects the state of data on the back end.

(Back end is Java / Google App Engine)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using AJAX:
There is a callback function included in it, which triggers asynchronously when the response of the request comes back from the server.
In this function you can call your page update functions to execute on the page updating processes.